# How do I link two sheets so that entering a numerical value in one cell of Sheet 1 produces an 'x' in the same cell of Sheet 2?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I know about the `importRange` function to link two sheets, but I wonder if there's a way so that when a cell's contents are imported to the second sheet, the second sheet will autopopulate the corresponding cell with simply an `x` and nothing else. So for example, if `Sheet1!B2` has a value of “23”, then `Sheet2!B2` will appear as `x`.

(I'm not familiar with JavaScript or Google Apps Script so any coding examples would be highly appreciated.)

Answer (score 1):

From inside the Google spreadsheet, go to Tools -> Script editor then try this:

```
function onEdit() {
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
   var r = s.getActiveCell();
   if( r.getColumn() == 1) { //checks the column
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var XSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
     ss.setActiveSheet(XSheet);
     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(r.getRow(), r.getColumn()).setValue("X");
     var MainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
     ss.setActiveSheet(MainSheet);   };
 };
}
```

This assumes your sheets are named Sheet1 and Sheet2, as is the default, and it's set to only watch column E (5) on Sheet1 for edits and only add an "X" to the corresponding cell in Sheet2.

Answer (score 1):

For a simpler solution you can use arrayformula:

Just put the following into Sheet2!A1 and watch the magic.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(isblank(Sheet1!A:Z),"","x"))
```

You can change the range `Sheet1!A:Z` to a specific range if you need, and you can put the formula into whichever cell you want the x's to start from.

Comment: Yes they are - will switch them